# Stop page reload when user hits "ENTER" in input field - ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, html, clojure, clojurescript

I am learning web development using Clojurescript and shadow-cljs and so far it has been awesome. I created a [really bad reddit viewing webapp](https://turmolt.github.io/reddit-viewer/) but have found that when the user first navigates to the site and clicks in the search field, then hits "ENTER" it will reload the page. I have added a (.preventDefault e) subscription to the onSubmit event, but it still reloads unless the user changes to the chart and back (adding # to the web-address).

Here is the reagent code that generates the input field:

```
[:input.form-control.mr-sm-2
  {:type "text"
   :placeholder "Aww"
   :aria-label "Search"
   :on-change #(rf/dispatch [:set-search-val  (-> % .-target .-value)])
   :onSubmit (fn [e] (do (.preventDefault e)
                         (identity false)))}]
```

2 Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong? I would like for the subreddit to refresh on enter, but if I can just get it to stop reloading I will be happy
2. Why does having # in the web address solve the problem?

[Here is the source code for anyone interested](https://github.com/Turmolt/reddit-viewer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to spell the attribute `:on-submit` (lower case, dashed), *(edit)* and it needs to be on the form, not the input.

Aside: you do not need a `do` to wrap the function body, and returning `false` in addition to calling `.preventDefault` on the event is redundant.

Comment: using :on-submit does not change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: I wrapped the input in a form tag, subscribed `(.preventDefault e)` to the `:on-submit`  and it worked! Thank you for the help